# Encode all data in one column and assign the same code if data has a same value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has appr. 100 columns and 20000 rows. Now I want to encode one categorical column so that it will have numerical code. After checking its value counts, the result shows something like this:

```
 df['name'].value_counts()

    aaa        650
    baa        350
    cad         50
    dae         10
    ef3          1
    ....
```

The total unique values are about 3300. So I might have a code range from 1 to 3300. I will
normalize the numerical code before train it. As I have already many columns in the dataset, I prefer not using one hot encoding method. So how can I do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate each group using ngroup(). It would look something like:

```
 df.assign(num_code=lambda x: x.groupby(['name']).ngroup())
```

I don't know what kind of information the column contains, however I am not sure it makes sense to assign an incremental numerical code to a column that seems to be categorical for training models.

Comment: You are great:) @Rik Kraan Thanks! It works very well